# Django App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Unable to Login to admin

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, django-admin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deploy a django app on EBS http://djangosample.elasticbeanstalk.com/

The 'It worked' message shows up fine in the browser. However I just can't login to /admin, it just loads and does nothing. The localserver  http://127.0.0.1:8000 works with the same credentials

Only changes I've made in settings is changing the default database to postgres.

Any ideas?

```
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
>         'NAME': 'postgres',
>         'USER': 'username',
>         'PASSWORD': 'password',
>         'HOST': 'sampledjangoapppostgresql.cmipujlbivbk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
>         'PORT': '5432',
>     } }
```

Comment: Did you forget to run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yeap did that already. Didn't help. The localserver is using the same postgres db

Comment: Its working for me: `http://djangosample.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/`

Comment: It loads, but you won't be able to log in. Whether I enter random or correct credentials, it just loads and loads. No error message whatsoever

Comment: @VictorYee did you ever get to the bottom of this? Having a similar problem now.

Comment: I have the same issue. Even by creating a super user, I still can't log into admin site

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned that you only changed db, but for me this was the problem.
I applied migrations and created a superuser on my ebs. Whenever I tried to login nothing happend, but when I used wrong credentials I got an error. So I assumed my db was setup correctly and had a record for my admin user. I used a seperate production settings file in which I had `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` (because django docs recommend this in production)." However I guess this failed the login, because I am not using https yet, but I am not entirely sure. After setting this value to false I could login to my admin panel. Hope this works for someone.